# Back in sometime or back to sometime？

Tags: phrases

I want to describe a picture that was taken in past, I should use the phrase "back in" or "back to"?

Ask for help

Comment: You can say the picture was taken back _in_ 1923, or that the picture dates back _to_ 1923. So you could use either of your options, depending on the rest of your sentence.

Comment: Yes, the question is unclear.  Does sometime refer to a specific date? Please offer some example sentences.